# How do I mock up an extended processing response from authorize.net?

Tags: php, symfony, payment-gateway, credit-card, authorize.net

We have an eCommerce site that is using `Authorize.net` as a payment gateway.

We have recently run into the issue of people submitting a payment confirmation, and then clicking submit again later on. This is resulting in a double-product situation, and/or double payment.

**Some things to consider:**

- The payment confirmation page is a result of a PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) which is loaded before the user submits their payment
- We have functionality in place that will actually act on each part of the request (see below for description of this)
- This situation will only apply when Authorize.net transactions take longer than normal.
- This is *NOT* in production yet, we are merely looking for a way to test this new functionality to prevent this behavior.

**The Prevention Piece**

We have a multi-step checkout form that follows the following process:

- Product selection
- Payment entry
- Confirm Order / Submit Payment
- Receipt

Each step of the process executes a call to a service that checks to see if the user has a current 'order' that has one of several statuses: `started`, `processing` or `complete`.

If the order is `started`, it will redirect them to the first page of the checkout flow.
If the order is `processing`, it will redirect them to a placeholder page that executes an ajax request every 2 seconds to check the status of the order. When the order is complete, they are redirected to the `receipt` page.
If the order is `complete`, they are redirected to the `receipt` page immediately.

**The Problem**

Since this functionality is really only valid when the processing transactions take a bit longer, it gives us problems testing it - for a few reasons:

1. Our dev server is slow, and it is more likely than not that `Authorize.net` will respond to our request before the page is even rendered by the application.
2. If we dummy the response up by using the PHP function `sleep()`, it blocks the thread and nothing runs, and we are in the same boat as [1].

**What we hope**

I do not know if there is a way to make `Authorize.net` respond to requests in a slower manner via some parameter, or if there is another way to accomplish this. I welcome ANY and ALL ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be testing directly against Authnet for this. Make your own Authnet "server" and have it delay its response to you. For unit test I wrote for my Authnet library I created my own fake server which sends back the appropriate response I need to test. You can do the same and have the "server" wait as long as you need to before sending back a response. The response doesn't have to be real for you to test a delay.